# How to stop webbrowser

Tags: excel, vba, webbrowser-control

Using the URL as an example which illustrates the problem, using Webbrowser embedded within a cell, upon DocumentComplete the specific URL continues to load additional content which causes the DocumentComplete to fire, again and again, have tried Webbrowser.stop without success.  Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xURL As String
    xURL = "https://investorshub.advfn.com/"
    Application.Speech.Speak "Starting Look Up", Speakasync:=True, Purge:=True
    WebBrowser1.Silent = True
    WebBrowser1.Navigate (xURL)
    End
End Sub
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    WebBrowser1.Stop
    Application.Speech.Speak " Look Up Completed ", Speakasync:=True, Purge:=True
    End
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is Suggestion from my side,

Please create BAT file with following code

`taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe /T`

'its an example for IE, you can modify depending on the browser

```
Dim Filepath As String

  Filepath = "C:\user\folder\..."  ' Full path of the BAT file
  Call Shell(Filepath & "\test.bat " & Filepath) ' replace the "test.bat" with your file name
```

Hope this will help you, please feel free to post your suggestions

Regards,
Kadhir Nataraj